# Cassandra is throwing server error while fetching the large data

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

We were fetching the large amount of data from a table with aggregation query.
it was working fine, But certainly it is throwing the following error in the cassandra logs :-

```
ERROR [Native-Transport-Requests-3] 2018-10-24 12:27:12,328 Message.java:623 - Unexpected exception during request; channel = [id: 0xedc3f080, L:/172.19.9.2:9042 - R:/172.19.8.69:35436]
java.lang.AssertionError: [] is not superset of [expire_date, start_date, stock]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.partitions.PartitionUpdate.add(PartitionUpdate.java:567) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.DataResolver$RepairMergeListener$MergeListener.onMergedRows(DataResolver.java:280) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredRowIterators$UnfilteredRowMergeIterator$MergeReducer.getReduced(UnfilteredRowIterators.java:556) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredRowIterators$UnfilteredRowMergeIterator$MergeReducer.getReduced(UnfilteredRowIterators.java:518) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.MergeIterator$ManyToOne.consume(MergeIterator.java:217) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.MergeIterator$ManyToOne.computeNext(MergeIterator.java:156) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:47) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredRowIterators$UnfilteredRowMergeIterator.computeNext(UnfilteredRowIterators.java:500) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredRowIterators$UnfilteredRowMergeIterator.computeNext(UnfilteredRowIterators.java:360) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:47) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.transform.BaseRows.hasNext(BaseRows.java:133) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.transform.FilteredRows.isEmpty(FilteredRows.java:50) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.transform.Filter.closeIfEmpty(Filter.java:73) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.transform.Filter.applyToPartition(Filter.java:43) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.transform.Filter.applyToPartition(Filter.java:26) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.transform.BasePartitions.hasNext(BasePartitions.java:96) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$SingleRangeResponse.computeNext(StorageProxy.java:2090) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$SingleRangeResponse.computeNext(StorageProxy.java:2062) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:47) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.transform.BasePartitions.hasNext(BasePartitions.java:92) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$RangeCommandIterator.computeNext(StorageProxy.java:2135) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$RangeCommandIterator.computeNext(StorageProxy.java:2100) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:47) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.transform.BasePartitions.hasNext(BasePartitions.java:92) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.pager.AggregationQueryPager$GroupByPartitionIterator.fetchNextRowIterator(AggregationQueryPager.java:226) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.pager.AggregationQueryPager$GroupByPartitionIterator.hasNext(AggregationQueryPager.java:210) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.pager.AggregationQueryPager$GroupByPartitionIterator$GroupByRowIterator.hasNext(AggregationQueryPager.java:370) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.SelectStatement.processPartition(SelectStatement.java:820) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.SelectStatement.process(SelectStatement.java:759) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.SelectStatement.processResults(SelectStatement.java:400) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.SelectStatement.execute(SelectStatement.java:378) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.SelectStatement.execute(SelectStatement.java:251) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.SelectStatement.execute(SelectStatement.java:79) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.processStatement(QueryProcessor.java:217) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.process(QueryProcessor.java:248) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.process(QueryProcessor.java:233) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.transport.messages.QueryMessage.execute(QueryMessage.java:116) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.transport.Message$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Message.java:517) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.transport.Message$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Message.java:410) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105) [netty-all-4.0.39.Final.jar:4.0.39.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366) [netty-all-4.0.39.Final.jar:4.0.39.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$600(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:35) [netty-all-4.0.39.Final.jar:4.0.39.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$7.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) [netty-all-4.0.39.Final.jar:4.0.39.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_91]
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$FutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:162) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.SEPWorker.run(SEPWorker.java:109) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
```

Not able to what exactly is the error.

Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE brodosmarketplace.article_supplier_info (
        ean text,
        condition text,
        sub_condition text,
        supplier_id bigint,
        expire_date bigint,
        price double,
        start_date bigint,
        stock bigint,
        PRIMARY KEY (ean, condition, sub_condition, supplier_id)
    ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (condition ASC, sub_condition ASC, supplier_id ASC)
        AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
        AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
        AND comment = ''
        AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
        AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
        AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
        AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
        AND default_time_to_live = 0
        AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
        AND max_index_interval = 2048
        AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
        AND min_index_interval = 128
        AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
        AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

cql query used :

```
SELECT ean, condition, sum(stock) as stock FROM article_supplier_info WHERE start_date <= currentDate AND expire_date > currentDate AND stock > 0 GROUP BY ean, condition ALLOW FILTERING
```

Comment: What minor version of C*, you use?

Comment: You should also describe your table and the query that you are executing

Comment: i have edited and uploaded schema and cqlsh query

Comment: @RahulPatel did you upgrade recently or made any other changes to the server? Any other information regarding your environment might be useful. From the stack trace it seems that you are c*3.10. Please confirm

Comment: 6 month ago we upgrade cassandra 3.9 to 3.10

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, rather just a suggestion.

Not an expert, but by looking at the [code](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/e225c88a65f2e8091f8ea6212c291416674882a1/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/partitions/PartitionUpdate.java) it seems like it is failing in following code block:

> ```
> public void add(Row row)
> {
>     if (row.isEmpty())
>         return;
>
>     if (row.isStatic())
>     {
>         // this assert is expensive, and possibly of limited value; we should consider removing it
>         // or introducing a new class of assertions for test purposes
>         assert columns().statics.containsAll(row.columns()) : columns().statics + " is not superset of " + row.columns();
>         staticRow = staticRow.isEmpty()
>                     ? row
>                     : Rows.merge(staticRow, row);
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         // this assert is expensive, and possibly of limited value; we should consider removing it
>         // or introducing a new class of assertions for test purposes
>         assert columns().regulars.containsAll(row.columns()) : columns().regulars + " is not superset of " + row.columns();
>             rowBuilder.add(row);
>     }
> }
> ```

I hope this might help you to find issue in your code.

Comment: it is internally thrown by cassandra

Comment: Yes it is, may be looking at the internal code can help you bit more to troubleshoot the issue.